# How to incorporate AWS S3 plugin into Grails app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, grails, amazon-s3

How do I go about integrating [this S3 plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/amazon-s3) into my grails application? The documentation is very limited.

I have it fully installed with Quartz. And I have my AWS account, policies and bucket setup.

I want to be able to upload content for my Event domain class, with the content being uploaded being exclusive for each event object.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin you linked to looks very outdated, Last updated: `24 March 2010` and seems odd to depend on another plugin like quartz to use s3.

I would instead suggest Karman (maintained by the same person as asset-pipeline) and updated for Grails 2 & 3 https://grails.org/plugin/karman-aws?skipRedirect=true

Or you may just use the aws java sdk directly - it is straight forward api: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html

Comment: No problem, the other `aws-sdk` plugin Pavel mentions is a good option too. Feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[This plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/amazon-s3) is out of date.

I think it will be better to use https://grails.org/plugin/aws-sdk. This plugin supports S3 integration. You can find docs on github.